# How can I limit the number of queries when retrieving all related objects from multiple models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database, django-1.7

Lets say I have this model:

```
class MyLogModel(models.Model):
  log_stuff = models.CharField(max_length)

class MoreLogModel(models.Model):
  word = models.CharField(max_length)
  my_log_model = models.ForeignKey(MyLogModel, related_name="more_log_models")
```

Now imagine there are 1.000.000.000 MyLogModel and ten times more MoreLogModel which relate to them.

In my view I want to show the user the latest 100 MyLogModel and all the 'word' fields of the MoreLogModel that are relating to them. On average there should be 10 MoreLogModel per MyLogModel.

But if I just use (pseudo code):

```
my_log_model_query = MyLogModel.objects.get_latest_100
```

And then loop through it in the template always putting another loop:

```
{% for my_log in  my_log_model_query %}
  {% for more_log_model my_log.more_log_models %}
    {{ more_log_model.word }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

That will cause an insane amount of database queries right?

So what I'm wondering is if it is possible to query all MyLogModel with the related "more_log_models" already in a list attached to that model?

The reason why I have the foreign key relationship is because the data comes from a server process that is multi threaded and puts in the "word" whenever it feels like it.

So any ideas how I can solve this problem in general?

**Also:**
Another way I used before was to have only one model wich has a word field and a group_id. This word field then only contains one word and there is one entry for every word. That causes the 'log_stuff' to be duplicated, but I don't see a big problem with that. What was a huge problem is to go though all these logs and combine them according to the group ids and then sort them based on time again. In the end this causes less queries, but I have to sort everything at least twice which is not very fast.